# Dynamically update dictionary values in functions from other dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

Noob here trying to wrap my head around this idea I had. I know it's not pythonic or anything. Just trying to get a basic system working here but this is the closest to a functioning version of what I'm trying to do. Tried a bunch of things and can't seem to get the `options` to update properly. Really hope some feedback can point me in the right direction. Iv included the entire code, the part with the commented section in the `challenge()` function by `battleChoice` is my main issue. I can't get the `options` dictionary values to change to call different functions based on the current page.

```
import random



class Player:

    def __init__(self, name, element, attack, defence, hp, mp, alive=True, beatsEnemy=False):
        self.name = name
        self.element = element
        self.attack = attack
        self.defence = defence
        self.hp = hp
        self.mp = mp
        self.alive = alive
        self.beatsEnemy = beatsEnemy

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name


    def element():
        print()
        print(f'Hi {P.name}, your current element is {P.element}.')
        print()
        print("What would you like to change it to?")
        print()
        for key, value in elements.items():
                print(f"{key}) {value}")

        eleInp = input("---> ")
        if eleInp in elements.keys():
            P.element = elements[eleInp]
            print(f'You have successfully changed your element to {P.element}.')

        else:
            print("Invalid")

    def spells():
        playerSpells = {}
        for key, value in elements.items():
            if P.element in elements.values():
                playerSpells = P.element.spells
                pass
            else:
                pass


    def playerInput(self):
        running = True

        while running:    

            inp = input("---> ")
            if inp in options.keys():
                options[inp]()
                for key, value in options.items():
                    print(f"{key}) {value.__name__.capitalize()}")

            else:
                print("Invalid")


    def attacking():
        enemy = random.choice(basicEnemies)
        for keys, values in elementalStrengths.items():

                    if P.element in keys and enemy.element in values:
                        print("You have the elemental advantage!")
                        P.beatsEnemy = True
                        enemy.beatsEnemy = False

                    elif enemy.element in keys and P.element in values:
                        print("Enemy has the Elemental Advantage")

                        enemy.beatsEnemy = True
                        P.beatsEnemy = False


                    else:
                        Player.beatsEnemy = False
                        enemy.beatsPlayer = False



        battling = True
        while battling:



                if P.hp <= 0 or enemy.hp <= 0:
                    print("Battle ended.")
                    battling = False
                    if P.hp <= 0:
                        print("You died!")
                        P.alive = False
                    else:
                        print(f'{enemy.name} has died!')


                elif P.hp > 0 and enemy.hp > 0:
                    print(f'{enemy.name} - {enemy.hp} HP ')
                    print()
                    print(f'{P.name} - {P.hp} HP')
                    myDamage = enemy.defence - P.attack
                    enemyDamage = P.defence - enemy.attack
                    P.hp += enemyDamage
                    enemy.hp += myDamage
                    print(enemyDamage)
                    print(myDamage)
                    print(P.hp)
                    print(enemy.hp)







class SpellBook():
    pass





class StoryLine:

    def __init__(self, name, pageNumber, currentOptions, description, info):
        self.name = name
        self.pageNumber = pageNumber
        self.currentOptions = currentOptions
        self.description = description
        self.info = info


    def print_to_screen(self):
        print(self.name)
        print(f'Page Number: {self.pageNumber}')
        for key, value in options.items():
            print(f"{key}) {value.__name__.capitalize()}")
        print(self.description)
        print(self.info)



    def change_options(self):
        for key, value in options.items():
            print(f"{key}) {value.__name__.capitalize()}")



def challenge():                                    
    print("Challenge")
    print("You wish to battle?")
    battleChoice = {'1': "yes", '2':"no"}
    options = battleChoice
    Player.playerInput(battleChoice)
    #battleChoice = int(input("""1) Yes, 2) No
#---->"""))
    #if battleChoice == 1:
        #print("Commence Battle!!!")
        #Player.playerInput(battleOptions)
        #Player.attacking()


    #elif battleChoice == 2:
        #battle = False
        #print("You cowardly ran away...")
    #else:
        #print("----> ")


def stats():
    print("_Player Stats_")
    print()
    print(f'Element - {P.element}')
    print(f'Attack - {P.attack}')
    print(f'Defence - {P.defence}')
    print(f'Health - {P.hp}')
    print(f'Mana - {P.mp}')
    print()



def menu():
    print("Menu Page ")
    print()

    print("Menu Options ")
    print()


def exits():
    print("Thanks for playing!!! :) ")

    exit()








options = {'1': challenge, '2': stats, '3': menu, '4': Player.element, '5': exits}

battleOptions = {'1': Player.attacking, '2': "defend", '3': stats, '4': "items", '5': "run"}

elementalStrengths = {"Fire":["Earth", "Lightning"], "Earth":["Water", "Wind"], "Water":["Fire", "Wind"], "Wind":["Fire", "Lightning"], "Lightning":["Earth", "Water"]}



P = Player("Random", "Lightning", 15, 10, 100, 100, True)
E1 = Player("Slime", "Water", 15, 10, 20, 20, True)
E2 = Player("Ember", "Fire", 15, 10, 20, 20, True)
E3 = Player("Wisp", "Wind", 15, 10, 20, 20, True)
E4 = Player("Rots", "Earth", 15, 10, 20, 20, True)
E5 = Player("Spark", "Lightning", 15, 10, 20, 20, True)

E6 = Player("Armored Slime", "Water", 25, 25, 250, 250, True)


basicEnemies = [E1, E2, E3, E4, E5]

intEnemies =[]

advEnemies  = []




elements = { '1': "Fire", '2': "Water", '3': "Earth", '4': "Air", '5': "Lightning"}



intro = StoryLine("Introduction ", 1, (options), "This is the introduction page. ", "Introduces the game.")
intro2 = StoryLine("Introduction Two", 2, (battleOptions), "This is the second introduction page. ", "Introduces the game again.")





print("welcome player... ")
print(P.get_name())
intro.print_to_screen()
Player.playerInput(options)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you've declared `options` in a *global* scope and re-declaring it in a *local* scope inside the `challenge()` function. So when you update options locally, the global variable is not changed at all.

You have at least these two options:

#### 1)

State to `challenge()` that `options` is a reference to a global value and do the update:

```py
def challenge(): 
    # This call makes the magic happen  
    global options   
                           
    print("Challenge")
    print("You wish to battle?")
    battleChoice = {'1': "yes", '2':"no"}

    # Now options is globally updated
    options = battleChoice
    Player.playerInput(<it looks like this function is not suppose to receive any arguments>)
```

The problem with this is: your global `options` array is loaded as soon as the program starts, and it will not be loaded again. After the first change you make to it, it's values will never go back to what they were unless you explicitly make them go back to the original.

#### 2)

Parameterize `Player.playerInput()` to receive an `options` array and do what is supposed to, instead of retrieving it from the global context (I'm sure that this is a better solution in your case).

```py
    # Player's class
  
    def player_input(self, options):
        # Now your options are locally defined and will not be retrieved from the global context
        ... # Do what it was doing before
```

And on `challenge()`:

```py
def challenge():                                    
    print("Challenge")
    choice = input("You wish to battle?")
    if choice.lower() in ["yes", "y"]:
        Player.playerInput(battleOptions)
  
    elif choice.lower() in ["no", "n"]:
        battle = False
        print("You cowardly ran away...")

    else:
        # Default behavior..
```

Comment: Hi, could i trouble you to go into a bit more detail on the second option? i tried implementing it but it then requires 2 parameters? not sure if im calling it incorrectly but When i say Player.player_input(options) or (self.options)/ (intro) or any combination i cant seem to make it work,

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay in responding, do you still need help?

Comment: yes please if at all possible... thanks for getting back to me. i got it working with the global idea but id rather use it as a function. im just having trouble calling the function properly.

Answer (score 0):

In Player.element() is dictionary 'elements' (I hope it should be it) defined?

Then, in  Player.attacking() you iterate through the dictionary and you're doing next:

```
P.beatsEnemy = True
enemy.beatsEnemy = False
```

nothing changes here, cause you didn't say explicitly what value(it's linked with the key)you want to change. 
Also, assigning a value to a key has no sense.
You'd be better do this:

```
for key in dictionary.keys():
    if key == 'the condition you need':  # change it according to your needs
        dictionary[key] = 'the value you need'  # same, as above
```

that should work

Comment: Not too sure i follow the elements question? but that part of my functions have seemed to work as expected so far in terms of when it compares elements and stuff? i do have it defined all the way at the bottom as i cant quite figure out where it all belongs/works... xD      the values need to be assigned so that the game "pages"? i suppose for like the story can alter the values independently so that you can just press a number for what you wanna do instead of having to type. but i cant quite figure it out so i'll give your suggestion a shot, thanks :)